# KeyCloack integration wirh DRF (Django Rest Framework)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am a beginner level DRF developer. I am trying to integrate Keycloak with Django Rest Framework. Unfortunately, I was unable to find any type of help/blog/tutorial online.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use KeyCloack's Oauth2 API to authenticate and authorize your djagno users. Is is the same as implementing Sign-in with Google or any other provider.

My favorite package to implement social auth is [python-social-auth](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), and it even has an existing [backend for KeyCloack](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/keycloak.html).

Here is how a configuration for Oauth2 against KeyCloack should look like:

First, [setup social auth in your project like so](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html)

```sh
$ pip install social-auth-app-django
```

In your `settings.py`

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    'social_django',
    # ...
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.keycloak.KeycloakOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

# Add you connection settings here
SOCIAL_AUTH_KEYCLOAK_KEY = 'test-django-oidc'
SOCIAL_AUTH_KEYCLOAK_SECRET = 'a7a41-245e-...'
SOCIAL_AUTH_KEYCLOAK_PUBLIC_KEY = \
    'MIIBIjANBxxxdSD'
SOCIAL_AUTH_KEYCLOAK_AUTHORIZATION_URL = \
    'https://iam.example.com/auth/realms/voxcloud-staff/protocol/openid-connect/auth'
SOCIAL_AUTH_KEYCLOAK_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = \
    'https://iam.example.com/auth/realms/voxcloud-staff/protocol/openid-connect/token'
```

In your `urls.py`

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('auth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social'))
    ...
]
```

Then add this to your login page template:

```html
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'keycloack' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Login with KeyCloack</a>
```